# incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSString*' to parameter of type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char')

Tags: ios, xcode

This is the mistake:

incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSString*' to parameter of type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char')

I don't know what to do. Please show me my mistake.

```
{



NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",Name.text, Passwort.text];

NSString *hostStr = @"www....de.php";
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];






    BOOL loggedIn = [serverOutput isEqualToString: @"YES"];
    if (loggedIn)
    {
        [_LOGIN setEnabled:@"YES"];
    }
    else
    {
        [_LOGIN setEnabled:@"NO"];
        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Benutzername oder Passwort falsch"

                                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
_LOGIN.enabled = loggedIn;
if (!loggedIn)
{
    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] ...];
}
```

Comment: Your answer is better than mine ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
if (loggedIn)
{
    [_LOGIN setEnabled:@"YES"];
}
else
{
    [_LOGIN setEnabled:@"NO"];
    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Benutzername oder Passwort falsch"

                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
}
```

Don't use @"YES" or @"NO" when you call setEnabled method from the _LOGIN object. You should use YES OR NO :

```
[_LOGIN setEnabled:YES];
```

setEnbaled method need a boolean value as parameter, and when you sent @"YES" you send a string value to the method, that is not correct (since the method need boolean value).

Comment: There is 1 more mistake:
Unused variabled 'alertsuccess'




PS: Thanks to all, who write the answer to the other mistakes!

Comment: You declare an UIAlertView that you call alertsuccess but you don't use it, that's why. You should show the alert view using : [alertsuccess show];

Comment: Where should [alertsuccess show]; be/stand? Sorry for bad english, i'm german -.-

Comment: Just after this line : UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Benutzername oder Passwort falsch" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

Answer (score 0):

> [_LOGIN setEnabled:@"YES"];

Should be

> [_LOGIN setEnabled:YES];

You are using an NString to set what I assume is a BOOL value. The same also applies to the bit where you set it as NO also.